# Calculation in symfony doctrine update query

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine

We have a situation in which we need to update records based on existing data in table, this is query which i created manually, just to explain this query updates prize field data using amount field by subtracting its 51 percent value.

```
update users set final_amount = amount-(amount*51/100) where id = 1
```

here is my symfony code

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()           
   ->update('Users')              
   ->set('final_amount',"'". $amount."'") 
   ->where('id =1')->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That easy to do, there is even examples [in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries).

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('users')
    ->set('final_amount', 'amount-(amount*51/100)')
    ->where('id = ?', 1)->execute();
```

The DQL parser is smart enouth to detect colums in the set part.

By the way, do not use `->where('id =1')` but `->where('id = ?', 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got it right. It is as simple as:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
           ->update('Users')
           ->set('final_amount', $amount - $amount * 51 / 100)
           ->where('id = 1')
           ->execute();
```

Comment: I think `amount` is a table column, not a variable. But the question is not accurate on that :(